# how to set default values in spring form input tags

Tags: spring, jsp

I am using spring form input tags in my JSP page. Properties are mapped using hibernate mapping file

```
<td>Package<form:input path="commandObject[${loop.index}].name"/></td>
```

I have some default values in my database. I want to show the default values when user renders the form. And the modifications to those values should be saved as a new row in the DB.

How can I achieve this! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the default values in your controller and assign those to the properties in your pojo.

`private static final String alpha = "apple";`

`public String name = alpha;`

and you getter and setter methods asusual!

Comment: i have like 32 fields in the form...is there a way to do it in controller by getting the values from DB!

Answer (score 0):

above answer is one way, which owrks if you have default values which will never change. To get the defaults from database, Have a business layer in which we retrieve the defaults from Database and save them to the list. Use the list to show them in Jsp, even when we edit and submit vedited values will save as new row instead of updating the defaults.